# unexpected non-void return value in void function (swift)

Tags: swift

I'm getting the following error from the code below. I don't know how to fix this error and I can't really find a helpful answer.

> unexpected non-void return value in void function

```
 private func collectionView( _ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "a11", for: indexPath)
    
    return cell ;
 }

 func UICollectionViewCell() {
 
 }
```

Comment: Could you please check Apple docs first https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/1618029-collectionview

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition of `func collectionView( _ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` is not defining a return value but your function is returning a `UICollectionViewCell`. This is the cause of the problem. Also, you probably wouldn't want to make `cellForItemAt` a private method either. You should update it to

```
func collectionView( _ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "a11", for: indexPath)
    
    return cell ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to add to your function return value and remove a private keyword

   func collectionView( _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
   cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   let cell = collectionView
   .dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "a11", for: indexPath)

   ```
        return cell
   ```

   }
2. Remove this code

   func UICollectionViewCell() {

   }
3. Check if cell this ID "a11" is registered. (In storyboard or in code, depending on your implementation).

Can you provide the text of Error, please?